# Model with Matched pairs and repeated measures

Tags: r

I will delete if this is too loosely *programming* but my search has turned up `NULL` so I'm hoping someone can help.

I have a design that has a case/control matched pairs design with repeated measurements. Looking for a model/function/package in `R`

I have `2` measures at `time=1` and `2` measures at `time=2`. I have Case/Control status as `Group` (2 levels), and matched pairs id as `match_id` and want estimate the effect of `Group`, `time` and the interaction on `speed`, a continuous variable.

I wanted to do something like this:

(`reg_id` is the actual participant ID)

```
speed_model <- geese(speed ~ time*Group, id = c(reg_id,match_id),
        data=dataforGEE, corstr="exchangeable", family=gaussian)
```

Where I want to model the autocorrelation within a person via `reg_id`, but also within the matched pairs via `match_id`

But I get:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = speed ~ time * Group, data = dataFullGEE,  : 
variable lengths differ (found for '(id)')
```

Can `geese` or GEE in general not handle clustering around 2 sets of id? Is there a way to even do this? I'm sure there is.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Just thinking out loud now, but can I just use `id=match_id`, since that would also be capturing within person autocorrelation on top of within match? Or am I speaking nonsense.

Comment: Or do I simply need to do `id=reg_id` and then add the variables used for the matching (e.g. `age handedness weight height`) into the model. This is what has been recommended by some colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

This is definatly a better question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), but since you have exactly 2 observations per subject, I would consider the ANCOVA model:

geese(speed_at_time_2 ~ speed_at_time_1*Group, id = c(match_id),
        data=dataforGEE, corstr="exchangeable", family=gaussian)

Regarding the use of ANCOVA, you might find [this reference](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16895814) useful.

Comment: Well I don't have 2 observations per subject, but two observations and two time points (4 total observations). Does that change the model/code?

Thank you!

Comment: And the way you have it coded, I would need to `spread` the data from long to wide, based on time, correct?

Comment: Regarding your second comment, yes, you would need to spread the data so that you have one column with the `speed_at_time1` and another for the `speed_at_time2`. Regarding your first comment, do you have two measures per subject at time 1 because there is some amount of error in your measurement and you want to improve the accuracy through multiple measurements, or for some other reason?  If  the answer is yes, then it may make sense to average the two measurements so that you have just one (more accurate) estimate of the speed per time point per subject.

Comment: There is an event at, lets say, time 0. We took the measurement at time -1 and time -2 and then time +1 and time +2. Regarding the phenomenon, we aren't expecting any linear trend over the four years, but just the change from pre to post event at t=0. So I was treating to two observations at pre and two at post as equiavalent, time-wise.

Comment: Since you're treating the pre- and post-event observations as equivalent, you won't loose power or introduce bias your results by averaging them.  Also, depending on how you want to interpret the results you may prefer to use a [random effects model rather than GEE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/when-to-use-generalized-estimating-equations-vs-mixed-effects-models).